# Video fullscreen triggering scroll event

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating this website where users post media. As the user scrolls down, media elements that refer to older posts get appended. When the user scrolls to the top, a get request is sent to the server to get new posts. All the media elements are removed in the page and get added again(like a refresh). The problem is when I click on the video fullscreen button, it moves the scrollbar up and triggers the scroll event , causing my page to refresh.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling all the pointer events for the video container. Hence it won't allow scrolling.

```
pointer-events:none;
```

Also if you're opening the video in a modal, you can set a specific width and height for the video and set overflow to hidden so that the scroll bar won't appear.

```
.wrapper-video{
  height: 450px;
  width: 800px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Let me know if that helped!